# Angular.js detached elements reinserted into DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build custom directive which is responsible for rendering items from collection. Since I'm working with column layout I need to recalculate fitting columns after screen is resized and move items to new positions in DOM without destroying them and keeping their current state.

**The problem** after element is detached from DOM and reinserted back into correct position the directives that were working before on that element does not work anymore. It seems that if element is detached from DOM - scopes are not working anymore.

**Question** how can I make it work so that reinserted DOM elements works as expected?

Comment: Please show your existing code, may be create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: After I made a fiddle I found out that I made a mistake and I was not detaching elements from DOM (I thought I was). Before I detached them from parent element I removed parent element entirely from DOM which resulted in elements destruction. But interesting thing was that when elements are destroyed their scopes will not be destroyed. And since I was still holding reference to DOM element I was able to insert them back into DOM but they were not linked with their original scopes anymore...